# UIScrollview Scrolling in vertical and horizontal ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

This issue sounds a common problem I believe. I am trying to achieve scrolling in both directions (vertical and horizontal) but one at a time (shouldn't be diagonally). I am downloading images and placing it on a scrollview with 3 imageviews (use them in a circular way). But I am not sure how to proceed with vertical scrolling of images as I am able to do it for horizontally. I am having pagination on horizontal scroll at the moment. Eg:

```
1.0   2.0   3.0    4.0
      2.1   3.1
      2.2
      2.3
```

I am able to achieve infinite scrolling with lazy loading horizontally. How to display 1.1, 1.2 or 2.1 , 2.2 etc images? What's the best approach to achieve scrolling vertically with horizontally?

```
   1.0   2.0   3.0    4.0
```

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones.

Answer (score 2):

you can disable diagonally scroll by

```
scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

still not clear about what is your problem... if you can do horizontally scroll, you should be able make it works for vertically as well.

Comment: I know I can make use of directionalLocalEnabled. I have been using it already though. The mess is my current ContentSize is  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 460); and when I add 2 more imageviews then I will have to increase the contentsize in Y dimension, this will lead to diagonal scrolling of images.

Comment: have you use `scrollView.pagingEnabled`? if page size match to image size and directionalLockEnabled then you should not see partially scrolled image

Comment: I have turned on the paging for horizontal scrolling of images.